# Как создать уникальный индекс MySql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, индексы

Таблица Values: id(prim key), user1(int), user2(int), value(float)

Создал индекс unique для user1(int), user2(int). Но он работает не так как я хотел.

Нужно избежать дубликатов в столбцах user1 и user2.

```
user1 = 1 user2 = 2
user1 = 1 user2 = 3
```

Тут все ок. При добалении:

```
user1 = 1 user2 = 2 - ошибка. Тут тоже все ок.
```

**Но!** при добалении:

```
user1 = 2 user2 = 1 - ошибки нет!
```

MySql добавляет запись. **Но для меня это дубликат**! так как эта пара пользователей уже есть!

Как создать такой уникальный индекс?
Создавать еще столбик с хешем md5(min(id)+max(id)) ? и делать по нему индекс?

**Обновление**

```
CREATE TABLE `guillaume777_profile_matches` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profile_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `match_profile_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `skills_match` float(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `personality_match` float(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `global_match` float(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gen_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Profiles_Index` (`profile_id`,`match_profile_id`) USING HASH,
  KEY `GlobalMatchIndex` (`global_match`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошая идея про хэш, только как Вы написали работать не будет (1+4 = 3+2). Лучше md5(min($ids) . '|' . max($ids)) - это на php. Хэш из конкатенации минимального, какого-то нечислового разделителя и максимального.

В принципе, даже не обязательно хэш. Можно просто строку хранить.

Можно сделать триггер. 
Например, так

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_user_pair_hash` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.hash_column = CONCAT_WS( '|',  LEAST(NEW.user1, NEW.user2), GREATEST(NEW.user1, NEW.user2))
```

На update то же самое, только вместо BEFORE INSERT, BEFORE UPDATE

Comment: Я решил проблему без хеша, и тригерров..

Comment: myvzar, поделитесь решением

Comment: В юзер1 пишу min($id) а в юзер2 max($id). А дальше работает мой уникальный индекс

Comment: Я конечно надеялся что в мускуле есть "двухсторонний" (сам придумал) уникальный индекс... но полазив по интернету такого не нашел

Comment: Да, тоже решение, если контекст Вашей задачи позволяет так делать. Однако, на уровне базы неисключено появление дублей([1,2] и [2,1])

Comment: Запись у меня только в одном месте. Буду с пхп не допускать дубляжей... а так, то вы правы.. но мне пока подходит!

Answer (score -1):

Создай юник кей только по `(user1, user2)`.

**Обновление**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798555/use-multiple-columns-as-unique-identifier-for-mysql

Убери NOT NULL из столбцов. которые в юник кей попадают. Если я правильно все понял.

Comment: создал. только для user1(int), user2(int). Но не работает. точнее работает так как я описал в вопросе

Comment: кинь сюда show create table \`твоя_таблица\`

Comment: Убрал... не помогло

Comment: и там по ссылке проблема как мне кажется не такая.